# Using `client` in different files seems to break my discord.js deploy command

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, typeerror

I want to use "client" in one or multiple "command "files aside my index.js, where client is defined.

```js
//index.js
module.exports.Client = client

//command-file.js
const index = require(../../index)
const client = index.Client
```

```js
//index.js
client.commands = new Collection();

const commandsPath = path.join(__dirname, 'commands');
const commandFolders = fs.readdirSync(commandsPath)
for (const dir of commandFolders) {
    const commandFiles = fs
      .readdirSync(`${commandsPath}/${dir}`)
      .filter((file) => file.endsWith('.js'));
      
      for (const file of commandFiles) {
        const command = require(`${commandsPath}/${dir}/${file}`);
        client.commands.set(command.data.name, command);
      }
    }
```

```js
//ping.js
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('discord.js');
const WebSocketManager = require('@discordjs/ws')
const index = require("../../index")
const client = index.Client

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('ping')
        .setDescription('Replies with Pong!'),
    async execute(interaction) {
        await interaction.reply(`:ping_pong: Pong! ${client.ws.ping}ms`);
    },
};
```

In my case I had the `ping.js` command, which in the beginning texted some random things, so I didn't need `client`. I wanted then some real numbers. The slash command was uploaded before so updating the file worked fine. Later though I tried to deploy another command and errors appeared.

```
        client.commands.set(command.data.name, command);
                                         ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\mydir\index.js:46:42)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1126:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1180:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1004:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:839:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1028:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\mydir\commands\fun\ping.js:3:13)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1126:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1180:10)
```

Just to clarify `index.js:16:42` is where my command handler is situated (first line of the error above)

`ping.js:3:15 is`

```
        const index = require("../../index")
                      ^
```

I tried to deploy another command and it worked just fine (client wasn't used)

Comment: There's not enough code for us to go off of here. The first sample obviously isn't even real code as it contains syntax errors. It appears that `command.data` is undefined, but we have no idea what `command` is. Please post a [mcve]

Comment: @CollinD just updated the question, hope it is enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really know what you tryed to do there but I use in the main file `global.client = new Client()` and works just fine, then you don't have to require it, just use it as `client`